# how i can find mathematical way to know the number of triangles are in the photo?

Tags: sequences-and-series, education

how i can find mathematical way to know the number of triangles are in this photo?

[image: 2]

I sure that the solution like sequence or series but how to find it ?

if I added new line so what is the number of triangles become?

thanks for all

Comment: @BrianM.Scott :sorry I dont know so delete my question or what ?

Comment: It’s okay to leave it. It’s likely to be closed, but that doesn’t hurt anything, and you might get an answer that you like better than the ones at the other question (though they were pretty comprehensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any triangle either has a top most vertex, or a bottom most vertex.

First, count triangles with a top most vertex.  Starting from the vertex at the top we have $6$ possible triangles.  The two vertices in the second row each have $5$ possible triangles, and so on.

The pattern continues:

$$1\cdot6+2\cdot5+3\cdot4+4\cdot3+5\cdot2+6\cdot1=56$$

Next, count triangles with a bottom most vertex.  Starting with the vertices at the bottom, there are $1+2+3+2+1=9$ such triangles.  In the second row from the bottom, there are $1+2+2+1=6$ such triangles.  Continuing we get $1+2+1=4$ and $1+1=2$ for the next two rows, finishing with $1$ near the top.  This gives us $22$ triangles with a lower most vertex.

Altogether, we have $78$ triangles.

Comment: Are the individual triangles counted in?

Comment: @SJuan76: They are.  See if you can follow my reasoning to see that all of the individual triangles are included in the count.

Comment: Ok, I see, of the top vertex one of them is with a "height" of 1, and the same with the other descending, account for the "up pointing" triangles, and the same for the "vertex down" triangles for the reversed triangles. thanks